# Getting "Terrain splat 0 is null" error

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I'm getting "Terrain splat 0 is null" error in Unity3d Engine while trying to compile project for android. But I don't even have a terrain in my project. Some time ago I created one, and then deleted (from scene hierarchy and from project's assets folder).

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you google it? https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Terrain+splat+0+is+null&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VnrnVJCfKcmE-QbQxYGYCw There still ought to be some kind of terrain reference somewhere, otherwise you wouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: I used google play games unity plugin from https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity. 
Now I deleted it from project, and everything ok.